# xcode macros objective c not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macros

In xcode if I type in if then hit escape it gives me an option to autocomplete to an if block macro.

I just saw that there is a list of objective c macros like this for example a is supposed to be alloc init call.

However when I type in a then hit escape it says no completions found.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not working because I tried typing a on a new line.

If I do this:

```
MyClass *myvar = a
```

then hit escape it worked.

I will close this question after the forced delay that stack overflow puts in is over

Comment: It doesn't work for me as well. I already tried your solution. How about other things like aa for NSArray *array or ma for NSMutableArray *array. It doesn't work as well